# pasarela de pagos payu

Tags: angularjs, ionic, payu

Quiero implementar la pasarela de pagos con payu en mi app ionic, no tengo la informacion bien clara acerca de lo que debo hacer he visto en la documentacion que debo emviar un formulario en formato json o xml, pero no se donde colocar ese formulario ni que pedir le al usuario par tal fin.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aquí tengo el formulario para pedir los datos al usuario

agradezco me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la verdad es que para responder exactamente a tu pregunta nos hace falta más información, nos podemos preguntar ¿A donde quiere enviar la información?. Pero como veo que tu problema también es no saber enviar la información ni en el formato que te piden ni como enviarla, te dejo código que te ayuda a traer datos de un formulario, pasarlos a `json` y enviarlos a una URL con método `POST`.

```
<div class="list">
  <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Numero de tarjeta" ng-model="data.numero_tarjeta">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" ng-model="data.nombre">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="MM" ng-model="data.mm">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="AA" ng-model="data.aa">
  </label>
  <label class="item item-input">
      <input type="text" placeholder="CVV" ng-model="data.cvv">
  </label>
  <button ng-click="enviarInfo(data)" class="button button-large button-positive">
      Enviar
  </button>
</div>
```

Este codigo HTML es tu formulario (es un ejemplo) donde defino todos los campos que necesito mas el tag `ng-model`, esto te ayuda a definir un modelo a tus campos que puedes manejar tanto en la vista como en el controlador. El modelo es `data` y data se compone de `data.numero_de_tarjeta`, `data.aa`, etc etc. El boton llama a una funcion enviarInfo(data) donde data es tu modelo, desde el controlador :

```
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
  .controller('PopupCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.enviarInfo = function(data) {
              var datos = {
                  numero_tarjeta: data.numero_tarjeta,
                  nombre: data.nombre,
                  mm: data.mm,
                  aa: data.aa,
                  cvv: data.cvv
              }
              $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: url,
                  data: datos,
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: "application/json"
              }).then(function(response) {
                      //Exito en el post
                  },
                  function(response) {
                      //Error en el post
                  });
          }

  });
```

En el controlador definimos la funcion

```
$scope.enviarInfo = function(data)
```

Esto lo hacemos para recibir la informacion, una vez recibimos armamos un arreglo:

```
 var datos = {
  numero_tarjeta : data.numero_tarjeta,
  nombre : data.nombre,
  mm : data.mm,
  aa : data.aa,
  cvv : data.cvv
}
```

Y dentro de nuestra funcion enviarInfo ocupamos la directiva `$http` que nos ayuda a hacer un request ya sea enviar o recibir información a una URL definida, en este caso `URL = URL` porque solo tu sabes ese valor.

Te dejo un Codepen en el cual vas a encontrar exactamente el mismo código pero puedes verlo de manera mas ordenada, obviamente el envió de la información no va a servir porque no tengo datos de prueba donde hacer un `post`, ni tampoco sé cual es tu intención.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/bwQBzpendpoint/create-a-new-order)

**EDIT**

Como ya lo conversamos, te aconsejo leer, estudiar y entender la API de tu metodo de pago PAYU, en especial para tu pais Colombia ya que el tratamiento de pago es distinto para cada pais.

[Api PAYU en español para Colombia](http://developers.payulatam.com/es/api/payments.html#separator)

Comment: Para que le pones un timeout a la petición y escribes `JSON.stringify` cuando puedes pasar el objeto directamente? Por defecto las peticiones en angular son en json así que ese parámetro no es necesario.

Comment: @devconcept fue un ejemplo que copie de mis peticiones, voy a editarlo! gracias por el alcance

Comment: eso lo entiendo amigos e incluso ya lo tenia lo q no entiendo es este formato json q colocan en la documentacion de payu

Comment: POST /payments-api/4.0/service.cgi HTTP/1.1 
Host: sandbox.api.payulatam.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: length
{
   "test": false,
   "language": "en",
   "command": "GET_PAYMENT_METHODS",
   "merchant": {
      "apiLogin": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "apiKey": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   }
}

Comment: Entonces re-formula tu pregunta y deja toda la informacion necesaria para ayudarte....

Comment: Edite mi respuesta

Comment: amigo para implementar la pasarela de pagos estoy en cero solamente tengo el formulario para guardar y no se que mas camino cojer

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRodriguezDiaz Deberias leer la documentacion de la API de tu metodo de pago, estan todos los metodos que puedes usar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47078/discussion-between-francisco-jose-rodriguez-diaz-and-sioesi).